# How to use Raise a value error when calculating derivatives using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

``I need to Write a function which calculates the following math equation and round your answer to 2 decimal places: z = π*e**x**2/4y.

There are the following contstraints: The input variables x and y are single values (that is, not a list/array). If a division by zero occurs, raise a ValueError. Output should be rounded to 2 decimal places. (hint) You can calculate  ex  using the NumPy function np.exp(x).

I have done the following but still fail the value error tests (ValueError
Inputs: [0.5, 0]
def test_question_3_ValueError(test_input)):

```
def custom_function(x, y):
# your code here
a = (np.pi*np.exp(x**2))
b = 4*y
z = a / b 
if b < 0:
    raise ValueError("Div by zero")

return round(z, 2)
```

Comment: What have you tried to validate that the inputs `x` and `y` are not array-like?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, I believe that the division by 0, will only happen if y = 0, as b = 4*y, and b can be only 0 if y = 0, thus, you should change the if statement for b == 0.

Anoter thing, that if statement should be before calculating the z value, because you want to raise the Error before any computations has been started, and thus stopping everything that follows afterwards.